# Vue dynamic v-model within v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, v-for

I have the following fieldsets containing checkboxes:

```
<fieldset>
    <label v-for="(count, value) in availableFilters.level"><input type="checkbox" data-filterName="level" :value="value" v-model="level" @change="(e) => handleCheckbox(e, 'level')"> {{value}} ({{count}})</label>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
    <label v-for="(count, value) in availableFilters.subject"><input type="checkbox" data-filterName="subject" :value="value" v-model="subject" @change="(e) => handleCheckbox(e, 'subject')"> {{value}} ({{count}})</label>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
    <label v-for="(count, value) in availableFilters.delivery"><input type="checkbox" data-filterName="delivery" :value="value" v-model="name" @change="(e) => handleCheckbox(e, 'delivery')"> {{value}} ({{count}})</label>
</fieldset>
```

Notice there's a bit of repetition here, but it works. Here's my Vue instance:

```
var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        level: [],
        subject: [],
        delivery: [],
        availableFilters: {
            level: {
                "UG": 12,
                "PG": 12,
            }
        }
    },
    ...
```

I want something more like this so I don't have to repeat the same block over again:

```
<fieldset v-for="(filters, name) in availableFilters">
    <label v-for="(count, value) in filters">
        <input type="checkbox" :data-filterName="name" :value="value" v-model="name" @change="(e) => handleCheckbox(e, name, value)"> {{value}} ({{count}})
    </label>
</fieldset>
```

However, this doesn't work and it seems that the v-model is not bound to the data property. How do I correctly pass that now? The data property name will be whatever `name` is.

Comment: i think you should do `v-model="availableFilters[name]"`

Comment: It's not that property I'm trying to reference. availableFilters has a key called "level", but it's the data.level I'm trying to connect with. I tried even doing vm[name] but vm (the Vue instance to access it's data) is undefined.

Comment: yes i understood you, you want the selected items to inside the `level` array?

Comment: Yes. But not sure how to define v-model now when it's inside the v-for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To with situation you should put that properties (`level`, `subject`, `delivery`) inside an object called `selected` as follows :

```
 selected: {
    level: [],
    subject: [],
    delivery: []
  }
```

and you should loop using `v-for` like :

```
       <fieldset v-for="(filters, key,index) in availableFilters">
```

where the `filters` represents the value, `key` represents the key like `level` and `ìndex` represents the index such `0`, using the `key` item we could access `selected` like `selected[key]` so we could bind the checkbox to that property easily.

**Full example**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data() {
    return {
      selected: {
        level: [],
        subject: [],
        delivery: []
      },
      availableFilters: {
        level: {
          "UG": 12,
          "PG": 12,
        },
        subject: {

        }
      }
    }

  }
 
});
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>


<div id="app" class="container">
  <fieldset v-for="(filters, key,index) in availableFilters">
    <label v-for="(count, value) in filters">
        <input type="checkbox" :data-filterName="this[filters]" :value="value"  v-model="selected[key]" @change="onchange"> {{value}} ({{count}})
    </label>
  </fieldset>
  <pre>{{selected}}</pre>
</div>
```